# keep viewcontroller at the same position as where left

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have two viewcontrollers: `ViewControllerA` and `ViewControllerB`

`ViewControllerA` has a UITable with lots of cells. Each cell has a button in. And when you click on a cells button it navigates to `ViewControllerB` like this:

```
[[cell nav] setTag:indexPath.row];
[cell.nav addTarget:self action:@selector(naviguate:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
cell.nav.tag=indexPath.row;
```

Where `nav` is the button. And naviguate contains `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"link" sender: sender];` Where link is the segue from `ViewControllerA` to `ViewControllerB`

When I then navigate back to `ViewControllerB` using `performSegue` it goes back to the top of the table! Is there any way to keep `ViewControllerA` at the same position as where I left it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to do circular segues. You would be creating a new ViewControllerA each time.

You should use `dismissViewController:animated:` or `popViewControllerAnimated:` to get back to A instead. ViewControllerA will be the same as it was before, because it's the same VC and not a recreated one.